# My Springboard crashes and Stuck at Safemode

Tags: crash, springboard

Here's the Syslog:

```
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Injecting: com.apple.springboard [SpringBoard] (847.21)
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/1437987223IAPCrazy426353000.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBIconAccessoryImage checkoutAccessoryImageForIcon:location:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector checkoutBadgeImageForText:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [UIStatusBarTimeItemView contentsImageForStyle:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [UIImage defaultDesktopImage]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBSlidingAlertDisplay _defaultDesktopImage]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector resetCurrentImageToWallpaper
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBIconController updateNumberOfRootIconLists]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector renderedSizeOfNode:constrainedToWidth:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [CKBalloonView initWithFrame:delegate:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [CKBalloonView _canUseLayerBackedBalloon]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector layoutSubviews
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector addBalloonView:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [CKTranscriptCell initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector setSeparatorStyle:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector initWithFrame:style:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBBookmarkIcon icon]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector didMoveToSuperview
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector drawRect:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector initWithBadge:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBIconController noteNumberOfIconListsChanged]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector icon
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBDockIconListView shouldShowNewDock]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBIconView _labelImageParametersForIcon:location:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector initWithSize:label:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector setInDock:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBIconModel cacheImageForIcon:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBIconModel cacheImagesForIcon:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBIconModel getCachedImagedForIcon:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBIconModel getCachedImagedForIcon:smallIcon:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector updateDesktopImage:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector didMoveToSuperview
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector setStatusBarMode:orientation:duration:fenceID:animation:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector setStatusBarMode:orientation:duration:fenceID:animation:startTime:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector operatorNameStyle
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector setOperatorName:fullSize:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector drawRect:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): BTM: attaching to BTServer
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Alkaline.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/AppList.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/ApplockerActivatorToggle.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/BMUIKit.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/BackgroundManager.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/CCToggles.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBCCSettingsSectionController _updateBluetoothButtonState]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/ColorKeyboard.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): YS Bundle: com.apple.springboard
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/DisplayOut.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/FabiusCrack.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:19 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Flipswitch.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/GRDocumentImportRedirect.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/GamePlayerUI.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/IconSupport.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Infiniboard.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/JOCastle.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/JODebox.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/JellyLock7.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector viewWillAppear:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector viewWillDisappear:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/KeepSlowAnimation.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/LocalIAPStore.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector isSubscriptionActive:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector isFeaturePurchased:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector hasConfigurationError
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector hasClientError
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector hasServerError
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector transactionVerified
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector transactionIsDuplicate
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector clientServerTimeMismatch
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector validationExpired
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector isTestDevice
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector isJailbroken
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector objectWithString:error:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector objectWithString:error:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector getState
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector subscribed
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector hasReceipt:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector isFree
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector parseJSON:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector isFree
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector validateStatus
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector canStartDownloading
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector setObject:forKey:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector setObject:forKey:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [NSObject setObject:forKey:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector setObject:forKey:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/PasswordPilot.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Springtomize3.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): Welcome to Springtomize 3
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): Loading on 847.210000
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBDockIconListView iconColumnsOrRows]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/SwitchSpring.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/WinterBoard.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/applocker.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector appSwitcherSnapshotViewForDisplayItem:orientation:loadAsync:withQueue:statusBarCache:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector frontLocked:withAnimation:automatically:disableLockSound:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector applicationLaunched:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector iconTapped:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBBulletinBannerController _presentBannerForItem:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBBulletinBannerController _handleBannerTapGesture:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBIconView prepareForReuse]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/fono46xSpringBoardExtensions.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SpringBoard frontDisplayDidChange]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/libhide.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): LibHide: v2.4.1 initializer
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): LibHide: Querying system version
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): LibHide: returning version 7.000000
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): LibHide: Returning 0 icons hidden
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector init
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): LibHide: initializer completed and you're not in safe mode!
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/libstatusbar.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (user): CoreFoundation = 847.210000
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBApplication exitedCommon]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/stride2.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBUIController setLockscreenArtworkImage:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBUIPasscodeLockViewBase _updateStatusText:subtitle:animated:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBUIPasscodeLockViewWithKeyboard _updateStatusText:subtitle:animated:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBUIPasscodeLockViewWithKeypad _updateStatusText:subtitle:animated:]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/threedeeboard.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/xCon.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (user): dyld: Registered code signature for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/xCon.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/zeppelin_sb.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): Zeppelin initialized
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): Zeppelin: loading ios 7+
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): Zeppelin: init ios 4
Wed Jul 29 08:24:20 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/zeppelin_uikit.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:21 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): Loaded logger: SBAppInstallationLog
Wed Jul 29 08:24:21 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): Loaded logger: SBIconLog
Wed Jul 29 08:24:21 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): Loaded logger: SBWorkspaceLogging
Wed Jul 29 08:24:21 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): deviceColorRef: white
Wed Jul 29 08:24:21 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): deviceEnclosureColorRef: silver
Wed Jul 29 08:24:21 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): deviceColorRef: white
Wed Jul 29 08:24:21 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.springboard): deviceEnclosureColorRef: silver
Wed Jul 29 08:24:28 2015: SpringBoard (user): libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:200: string SBNonDefaultSystemAppTag is not a valid gestalt question
Wed Jul 29 08:24:28 2015: SpringBoard (user): libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:200: string hidden is not a valid gestalt question
Wed Jul 29 08:24:28 2015: SpringBoard (user): libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: stand-alone-contacts is static and will never generate a notification
Wed Jul 29 08:24:28 2015: SpringBoard (user): libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: still-camera is static and will never generate a notification
Wed Jul 29 08:24:28 2015: SpringBoard (user): libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: any-telephony is static and will never generate a notification
Wed Jul 29 08:24:28 2015: SpringBoard (user): libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: nike-ipod is static and will never generate a notification
Wed Jul 29 08:24:29 2015: ReportCrash (Crash Reporter): ReportCrash acting against PID 1754
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: ReportCrash (Crash Reporter): Formulating crash report for process SpringBoard[1754]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: ReportCrash (Crash Reporter): Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/SpringBoard_2015-07-29-082429_Ahmads-iPod-touch.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Injecting: com.apple.springboard [SpringBoard] (847.21)
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: Entering Safe Mode
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/MobileSafety.dylib
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector touchesEnded:withEvent:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector mouseDown:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector _updateTimeString
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector _finishUnlockWithSound:unlockSource:isAutoUnlock:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector _unlockWithSound:isAutoUnlock:unlockSource:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector _unlockWithSound:isAutoUnlock:unlockType:
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [SBIconController showInfoAlertIfNeeded]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector maxIconColumns
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: message not found [UIImage defaultDesktopImage]
Wed Jul 29 08:24:30 2015: SpringBoard (com.apple.console): MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector tile
```

Comment: Nice you pasted the log, but can you read it ? it needs formating to be readable.

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere if you do a firmware restore it should fix the problem with Springboard. I assume you know how to do that.

If you wish to take closer look it is in the

Saved crashreport to `/var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/SpringBoard_2015-07-29-082429_Ahmads-iPod-touch.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0`

I also took the liberty to format your post in to a readable format.